# jbutton id not showing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I just created a simple imagepanel and add a button on the panel

Can any body tell me wats the problem in code?

Image is displaying but button is not

```
package inventorymanagement;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImageTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("E:/Desktop[/icon/6470729-exclamation-mark-icon-button-3d-red-glossy-circle.jpg").getImage());
JButton jButton1=new JButton("jButton1");
panel.add(jButton1);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);

}
}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

private Image img;
public ImagePanel(String img) {
this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
}

public ImagePanel(Image img) {
this.img = img;
Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
setPreferredSize(size);
setMinimumSize(size);
setMaximumSize(size);
setSize(size);
setLayout(null);
}



public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the layout for the panel

Just add `panel.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());` before adding the button `panel.add(jButton1);`.

Answer (score 0):

when you `setLayout(null);` you need to setBounds to all your component. You should read these tutorial:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html